# How best to upload data to a database table and prevent duplicate entries?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to prevent duplicate copies in a table. I am looking for duplicates where the entire row is a copy of another row. If one element of a row is a copy of somehting from another row, that is not a problem. For example, if the name is repeated in multiple fields, that is ok but if each additional field is the same as another entry, then I would like to prevent my program from adding the entry. Here is what I was going to try:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = '$field1',field2 =     '$field2', field3 = '$field3',field4 = '$field4'"))){
// send some message if entry is within table
} else {
// add unique entry to the table if field is not there
}
```

Will the above code search and check to see all 4 values are within each row or if all 4 values are located somewhere in each column but not necessarily in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE( field1);
```

And than use insert into with [`ignore`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) keyword:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table ...;
```

That way:

- you'll have only one query to database
- no error will be triggered
- no duplicity will occur in database (guaranteed by database)

This is nice reading: [INSERT IGNORE or INSERT WHERE NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222443/insert-ignore-or-insert-where-not-in)

Comment: would that make it so that the table would not add any entries that had the same name as field1? Can I change the above so that the other fields are also considered within the same row?

Comment: @Stagleton what do you know about `UNIQUE KEYS`? They ensures that data are unique in table, if you crate index `UNIQUE (name)`, you can insert each name just once (the other try creates a failure). When you create it on `UNIQUE (category_id, product_id)`, you can insert `(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)`, but reinserting `(1,1)` will trigger error. When you use `INSERT IGNORE`, error won't be produced, query will just silently stop. You also may use `ON DUPLICATE` (see link at the end of my answer).

Comment: I don't know enough. I'll try that when I get home. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.` this is all that mysql manual provides and found so far (Jakub Vrana wrote perfect article about using unique keys some time ago http://php.vrana.cz/vyuziti-unikatnich-klicu-v-databazi.php but it's in Czech but you'll may understand it with little help of google translator).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly. I had unique fields except for the date and I got an error because the date field was a repeat

Comment: nevermind, because there were already duplicates within the table, an error message was thrown